# Runs View Model data through concurrent service calls to get data for Entity Type

Tags: c#, performance, object-oriented, asynchronous

I have a few issues with the following code...

```
private async Task<EntityType> FillEntityDataAsync(ViewModel viewModel)
{
```

First, I'm thinking I need some sort of intermediate/domain model between the ViewModel and the Entity to clean this up...

```
    var typeAObj1 = new Response<TypeA>();
    var typeAObj2 = new Response<TypeA>();
    var typeBObj = new Response<TypeB>();
    var typeCObj = new Response<TypeC>();
    var typeDObj = new Response<TypeD>();
```

...except I'd like to try and run the following service calls concurrently, which would make the preceding types:

```
Task<Response<TypeA>>
```

etc. Normally I'd just do `Task.WhenAll()` for the calls, but I think the conditional blocks are tripping me up.

```
    typeAObj1 = await _someService.GetTypeAData();

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.vmProp1)
    {
        typeBObj = await _someService.GetTypeBData();
        typeCObj = await _someService.GetTypeCData();
        typeDObj = await _someService.GetTypeDData();
    }
    else if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.vmProp2)
    {
        typeAObj2 = await _someService.GetTypeAData(viewModel.vmProp2); 
    }

    var newEntityObj = new EntityType
    {
        SomeProperty = "",
        AnotherProperty = typeAObj1.Data?.Property1,
        AThirdProperty = typeAObj2.Data?.Property2,
        Prawpertee = typeBObj.Data?.TypeBProp,
        LastOne = typeCObj.Data?.TypeCProp,
        JustKidding = typeDObj.Data?TypeDProp
    } 

    return newEntityObj;   
}
```

So I'm trying to clean this code up, and figure out the best way of running these calls concurrently. How do you suggest going about that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: It appears your code is not working as intended as the current code runs each task after the previous task has completed and you are looking for a way to runs tasks concurrently.